# Using MvvmCross, what are best practices for transforming models to view models to show in lists?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvmcross

I have a data model which cannot be changed, say:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userid")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "complete")]
    public bool Complete { get; set; }
}
```

Online service returns ObservableCollection. I would like to show this in my view, but I need to add PropertyChanged, and a few static Actions relating to Complete being toggled, perhaps using MvxViewModel as a base class. What are some good MvvmCross ways of transforming the model to a view model while still ensuring that changes in the view model change the model? Would you have a reference to the original object in the view model object?

```
public class ToDoItemViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private TodoItem _item;

    public ToDoItemViewModel(TodoItem item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public Guid UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return _item.UserId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_item.UserId == value) return;
            _item.UserId = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => UserId);
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _item.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_item.Text == value) return;
            _item.Text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Text);
        }
    }

    public bool Complete
    {
        get
        {
            return _item.Complete;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_item.Complete == value) return;
            _item.Complete = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Complete);
            CompleteChanged.Invoke(_item);
        }
    }

    public static Action<TodoItem> CompleteChanged;
}
```

If so, is it possible to automatically generate this so that instead of re-writing all the properties in the ViewModel, it will track the model properties? Is it even wise to hold a reference to the original item in the viewmodel?

Here is how I am getting from an `ObservableCollection<TodoItem>` to `ObservableCollection<TodoItemViewModel>`

```
        var todoItems = await todoTable
            .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Complete == false)
            .ToCollectionAsync();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<TodoItemViewModel>(todoItems.Select(i => new TodoItemViewModel(i)));
```

**Update.** Slight shortcut

```
            Items = await _todoTable
                .Where(item => item.Complete == false)
                .Select(item => new TodoItemViewModel(item))
                .ToCollectionAsync();
```

Comment: You could just implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your model?